# WhatsApp iCloud backup stuck at 0% and just won't move

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

Last successful backup of WhatsApp to iCloud was on 10th April 2019, since then the process keeps hanging.

My iCloud is as good as unused, it has 4.5 GB/5 GB available, so I doubt space is the issue.

Status is "Backing up..." and its hung at "Uploading: 0%"

What did I try:

- Updated iOS to 12.3.1.
- Updated WhatsApp to version 2.19.61.
- Deleted WhatsApp data from iCloud Drive and tried to backup again. Instead of getting stuck at 0% it then got stuck at 3%.
- In iCloud Drive, turned WhatsApp "Off" and "On"
- Hard reset on iPhone

Nothing works! Anyone tips or the same problem?

Comment: To debug, can you check the upload speed of your Internet connection using a tool such as [Speedtest](https://www.speedtest.net)?

Comment: Hi @NimeshNeema - My internet speed is +50mbps - so don't think it is a network connectivity issue

Comment: Doesn't hurt to check. Connections tend to have a different upload/download speeds, with upload speed slower than download.

Comment: @NPJobs ever found a solution? I've done all the above and left my iPhone running the whole night and still woke up to 0%.  My internet is 100mbps...

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on iOS 13 and Whatsapp support magically got back to me.

**Whatsapp needs 2.05x the backup size available on your iPhone, and in its infinite wisdom *also in iCloud*.**  So if your backup is past 2.4ish GB, you are essentially forced to start paying Apple for additional iCloud storage.

I can personally verify this worked.  I tried everything (other troubleshooting steps include turning off iCloud Drive and deleting anything Whatsapp already put in iCloud).  After getting stuck randomly between 0%, 4% and 10% I moved to 50GB, flipped back to Whatsapp and it immediately continued progressing.

Maybe one day Whatsapp will let us manually backup to Google Drive or otherwise just spit out a file we can restore from...