# Whatsapp backup stuck at 0%

Tags: iphone, icloud, whatsapp.app

Same problem as [this person](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362590/whatsapp-icloud-backup-stuck-at-0-and-just-wont-move).  I want to run a whatsapp backup since I want to completely restore my phone to factory and not restore from backup.
My iphone is:

- Updated to latest iOS 13.2.2
- No whatsapp update available (version 2.19.112)
- Deleted whatsapp data in icloud
- Toggled whatsapp under "iCloud" and rebooted in between
- Verified my internet is working fine 100mbps+
- Used wifi & cellular*
- Have 4GB+ available in iCloud
- Have 25GB available on iPhone
- Backup size estimated at 2.38GB
- Seems like separate bug, it won't back up under cellular ("waiting for wifi") even though iCloud drive is on under cellular.

Comment: Instead of posting the same question again, please add any helpful details you can think of to the original question.

Comment: The question is dead and I've added clearly more information.  As we are 4 months later with new versions of Whatsapp and on iOS 13, it seems relevant that newer options might exist from the previous question on iOS 12.

Comment: Your first point of contact in such cases should be WhatsApp support in any case. Also, based on experience, asking practically the same question as somebody else did will not yield better answers (or any at all) as such.

Comment: Sadly whatsapp is not known for getting back to people...

Comment: I left an answer at the question I'm being marked duplicate at